# I'm trying to change column data type in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have problem with data type conversion in power query. I have data about total working hours ("[h]:mm:ss"-in this format) 
{[image: total working hours]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr0yL.png)

when I change data type to General in excel I get different outcome
[image: outcome in excel]

compare to power query
[image: outcome in power query]

I don't understand why power query gives me different result.

[excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zEAN2s1L_6_cYkmcisRncGeBrx8-C_rI/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106199553323365701540&rtpof=true&sd=true)

```
`let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Auda_A\Desktop\Data.xlsx"), null, true),
Table1_Table = Source{[Item="Table1",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table1_Table,{{"[h]:mm:ss", type number}, {"General", type number}})
```

in
#"Changed Type"`

and this is happening when i try to import data from other excel file, if I'm trying to import data from table (not from other excel file) it works fine and I get correct result.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Please provide more information, including your power query M code.

Comment: Could it be that you changed your Excel data and neglected to **Refresh** your Power Query?  The difference is one (1) day or 24 hours.

Comment: no, I think problem is this - if I use [h]:mm:ss format type and time is more than 24 hours it gives me this result - "1/1/1900  9:36:00 AM" - and if is less than 24 hours - "4:48:00 PM" - and power query tries to convert this time format in "Date/time" format automatically and gets wrong result, because when I change "Date/time" format into "number" format I get wrong result, also, when I turned off power query feature to automatically detect column type and than manually changed column type I get same result. if that makes sense.

Comment: but if time is less than 24 hours power query converts it corectly.

Comment: I think the discrepancy has to do with the way Excel stores date/time vs PQ (day1= 1/1/1900 vs 12/31/1899), and it probably all goes back to the Feb-29-1900 bug designed into Excel.  And apparently the manner in which PQ tries to compensate when reading from an open workbook vs an excel file.

Comment: Aside from what you show, is there a programming issue you are running into that we can help you with?

Comment: thanks for your answer, that's all, I was looking the way to fix this, I didn't find anything but to change time format to General in excel file and then import with power query.

Comment: But what are you trying to accomplish?  If it is to perform math operations on times within Power Query, there's no need to convert to a number (as there can be in Excel).

Comment: yes, you are right, but problem is that when I import that data its already changed and it doesn't matter whether I change format and perform calculations or I do it without converting it to a number. I get same result.

Comment: and also, I need result in number format, because it is cost of service. So it will be weird If I will have cost of service in time format.

Answer (score 1):

Power Query and Excel have different "base dates" for date times (31-Dec-1899 vs 1-Jan-1900)

Apparently, if you are importing the data from a File, PQ applies its own base date.

To convert that time into a duration that can be used to compute cost of service, you need to first convert that date into a duration, and then you can convert the duration into a number.

To convert the date into a duration, you subtract the base date for PQ (12/31/1899).

The following M-Code will convert data in an Excel file to the relevant number:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\Data.xlsx"), null, true),
    Table1_Table = Source{[Item="Table1",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table1_Table,{{"[h]:mm:ss", type datetime}, {"Number", type number}}),
    durations = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{"[h]:mm:ss", each Number.From(_-#datetime(1899,12,31,0,0,0))})
in
    durations
```

***Data.xlsx***
[image]

***Result***
[image]

Comment: thanks, it works.